# Regarding Layouts

Tags: android, android-layout

as i am new to Android ... I have a small doubt on Layouts?
which layout is better and preferable among all(i think there are 2 layouts if my guess is not wrong RelativeLayout,LinearLayout) layouts.

Comment: The name only suggest the usage of respective layouts, 1) when you want to align view horizontal or vertical linear way use linear layout 2) when want to align views based on/relative to other views use relative layout 3) when want to show table structured views use table layout 4) when want to show something as frame(means one view on above another i.e.photo frame) use frame layout

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are more then 2 layouts, used by needs:

FrameLayout : Layout that acts as a view frame to display a single object.

RelativeLayout :Enables you to specify the location of child objects relative to each other (child A to the left of child B) or to the parent (aligned to the top of the parent).

LinearLayout :A layout that organizes its children into a single horizontal or vertical row. It creates a scrollbar if the length of the window exceeds the length of the screen.

TableLayout :A tabular layout with an arbitrary number of rows and columns, each cell holding the widget of your choice. The rows resize to fit the largest column. The cell borders are not visible.

Comment: Niciforovi :: which is better?

Comment: there is no better, you use each of them how you need them. All are good its just matter of task you need to do. For example if you want to put 1 view in front of the other you would use Frame Layout, if you want your views to be one below other you would use LinearLayout with vertical oriantation etc...

Comment: It's worth noting that you can also have overlapping views in a RelativeLayout. You can also place layouts inside other layouts to achieve other, more complicated arrangements.

Comment: Yep, you decide which one to use based on what you have to do.

Comment: if you feel like my answer helped you consider marking it like that, if not please tell me how can I improve it.

Comment: you can click on thick below voting arrows so it turns green :)